# JVM not exiting

Tags: java

We have Java process which is triggered by `Autosys`.
We recently had some internal dependant jars upgraded and since then JVM spawned by `Autosys` is not exiting due to which `Autosys` is not showing job complete.

I have checked via jconsole and it shows this:

```
Name: Finalizer
State: WAITING on java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock@67871079
Total blocked: 13  Total waited: 14

Stack trace: 
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:118)
java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:134)
java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:159)
```

Any pointers on what this implies? 
There is no deadlock, i have checked via jconsole.

Answer (score 0):

It would imply in memory leak, possibly. That JVM not terminated may consume other resources, like CPU. I would suggest you to restore an old backup and try to pin point which jar caused the problem. And then report to the jar maintainer.